# How to Order SOLR Results?

Tags: solr, sunspot

I am using SOLR to generate search results from my data. Each document that has been indexed has a created_at (date) as well as some terms that I want to search for.

Currently, the results are ordered by created_at so that the newest results are on top.

I want to generally keep this order but allow searching for a term. When searching for a term, the existence of the term in the results should not be mandatory but I do want at least some of these products to appear high in the search even if they would normally be sorted out of view.

This presents a weird problem of trying to combine sorting and ranking. How have others handled similar problems?

Answer (score 4):

You can boost newer articles like described at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents